# Dropdown in emails

Tags: ios, iphone, drop-down-menu, tabular

I want to know if we can allow a drop down within a HTML mailer for iOS/Android devices. I want to show a dropdown based selection with which I can show data in the emailer. The data would be static and the user would have the liberty to choose to hide or show the data after choosing from the dropdown.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You would need javascript for that, but that is not available in the iOS Mail app (possibly not on Android either, but I wouldn't know) for security reasons.

And it will absolutely not work in any webmail client. That would be a huge security issue, since it would be really simple to write a worm.

Your best option is probably to have a link to a regular website, or just dump all the data on the email.

Comment: It's actually a table which I want to filter based on the selections by the user. Is there any other way i can show 6 columns of data without user having to scroll?

Comment: You might want to send a short list of data in the email, but include an interface that clearly shows there is more data available, like pagination links, sorting links in the header, or filter buttons. Then make all buttons/links in the mail open the exact same interface (but working) in a browser (make sure the sorting links each lead to a page sorted by that column, etc.). That would create a smooth experience for the user.